# How to calculate time between request and precedent request by rest web service in spring boot?

Tags: spring, api, rest

I am writing a Rest API using Spring boot.
I want to calculate time between a request and the previous request, and if the time is less than 2 min I want to return an object json, trace and black list the elements of the request.
How can i do this ?

Comment: Add more details in this question - do you want to track the interval between all requests, requests based on a parameter id, etc.

Comment: first of all I want to get the time between request and previous request.

Comment: you can maintain a static Date variable. Store the time of first request and compare with the next request.

Comment: can you give me more detail please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

private static long lastRequest = Long.MAX_VALUE;

@RequestMapping("/post")
public String postTest() {

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (currentTime - lastRequest < 120000){
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT
    } else {
        lastRequest = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did the same logic with LocalDateTime.now()
Thank you so much Sir

Comment: No problem. Just accept the answer if that is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any idea if we want to calculate currentTime - lastRequest for each User(because in your response you are calculating the time between two request for any request)

Comment: For each user you will need something to identify the user. REST architecture are normally stateless. What it is possible is the request to pass a header parameter to identify the user. You could create question here on stackoverflow about how to identify the user in a Rest request.